# Selecting a single check box in a jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a datatable with some json data. I have added a checkbox in every row but the problem I want to be selecting a single row at a time. i.e when I click on a check box on one row the other check boxes not to be selected. i.e to behave like a radio button.Where am I going wrong with my code.
table

```
<div>
    <h1>Accounts Table</h1>
    <table id="employeesTable" class="display">
       <!-- Header Table -->
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- Footer Table -->
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Jquery datatable

```
$(document).ready( function () {
     var table = $('#employeesTable').DataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "/account/list",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
            "aoColumns": [
                  { "mData": "id"},
                  { "mData": "account_type" },
                  { "mData": "amount" },
                  { "mData": "date" },
                  { "mData": "description" },
                  { "mData": null,
                   className: "center",
                defaultContent:'<input type="checkbox" name="name1"/>' }
            ]
     }

)

     $('input[name="name1"]').on('change', function() {
          var checkedValue = $(this).prop('checked');
            // uncheck other checkboxes (checkboxes on the same row)
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=""]').each(function(){
               $(this).prop('checked',false);
            });
            $(this).prop("checked",checkedValue);
    
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit properties values by loop only the checked checkboxes:

```
$('input[name="name1"]:checked').each(function(){
   $(this).prop('checked',false);
});
```

And when getting table values from ajaxcall, Include onchange of the element in initComplete attribute of datatable,.. like below (because datatable checkbox HTML element will accessible once fully loaded from ajax, untill it won't accessible. So onchange for checkbox is not applied here...)

```
"initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
   $('#employeesTable tbody input[name="name1"]').on('change', function() {
var checkedValue = $(this).prop('checked');console.log(checkedValue);
  // uncheck other checkboxes (checkboxes on the same row)
  $('input[name="name1"]:checked').each(function(){
     $(this).prop('checked',false);
  });
  $(this).prop("checked",checkedValue); });  },
```

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#employeesTable').DataTable({
     "aaData":[
      {

        "id": "1",
        "description": "Tiger Nixon",
        "account_type": "System Architect",
        "amount": "$320,800",
        "date": "2011/04/25",
         "name": "Tiger Nixon"
      },
      {

        "id": "2",
        "name": "Garrett Winters",
        "description": "Garrett Winters",
        "account_type": "Accountant",
        "amount": "$170,750",
        "date": "2011/07/25"
      }],
    //"sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/test.php",
      "sAjaxDataProp": "",
      "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
"initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
   $('#employeesTable tbody input[name="name1"]').on('change', function() {
    var checkedValue = $(this).prop('checked');//console.log(checkedValue);
      // uncheck other checkboxes (checkboxes on the same row)
      $('input[name="name1"]:checked').each(function(){
         $(this).prop('checked',false);
      });
      $(this).prop("checked",checkedValue);

  });
  },
      "aoColumns": [
      { "mData": "sel",
             className: "center",
          defaultContent:'<input type="checkbox" name="name1"/>' 
},
            { "mData": "id"},
            { "mData": "name" },
             { "mData": "description" },
            { "mData": "account_type" },
            { "mData": "amount" },
            { "mData": "date" },                  
      ]
});


  $('#employeesTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<div>
    <!--<h1>Accounts Table</h1>-->
    <table id="employeesTable" class="display">
       <!-- Header Table -->
       <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- Footer Table -->
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @ikiK your code works very well. But when I replace the "aaData" with  "sAjaxSource":/account/list" that has my json data then they loose the state  ie they don't behave like radio buttons

Comment: @user3736334 , The problem is during get data ajax aoColumns->mData 
Html DOM element will load once ajax call complete... so onchange function not accessible with input checkbox...

Comment: @user3736334, Now i updated the code in my script ... so we need to put onchange event it in initcomplete attribute of Datatable ... because initcomplete will call after ajax data loaded fully...

Answer (score 0):

Your description is little unclear, but if this is what you need?
Your input:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=""]')
```

is not finding anything or maybe itself. `closest` is finding ONLY ancestors.

HTML markup goes: `table  > thead OR tfoot > tr > input`
you got stuck at `tr` and ignored `thead` and `tfoot` you need to find witch of those is it and find inputs inside.

```js
$('input[name="name1"]').on('change', function() {
  var section = $(this).parents("tr").parent().get(0).nodeName
  console.clear();
  console.log(section);
  if (section === "THEAD") {
    $("tfoot * input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  } else if (section === "TFOOT") {
    $("thead * input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Accounts Table</h1>
  <table id="employeesTable" class="display">
    <!-- Header Table -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Name <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Amount <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Date <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Description <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Active <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Footer Table -->
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Id <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Name <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Amount <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Date <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Description <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
        <th>Active <input type="checkbox" name="name1" /></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```